# angular.element.addClass wired

Tags: javascript, class, angularjs, directive

I'm learning from tutorial [EggHead angular.element](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_6ijcqI5fi8&feature=share&list=PLP6DbQBkn9ymGQh2qpk9ImLHdSH5T7yw7) and following it to create testing scripts.
But my angular.element's behaviour is different then tutorial.
The toggleClass or addClass will add the "class" to both "input" and "div". see below script and picture. Is it a bug? or I'm missing something?

```
<html ng-app="app">
  <head lang="en">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Debug</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/foundation.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <dumb-password></dumb-password>
    <script src="/js/angular-1.2.0rc1/angular.js"></script>
    <script>
    angular.module('app', [])
    .directive('dumbPassword', function () {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<div><input type="text" ng-model="model.input"><div>{{model.input}}</div></div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
          scope.$watch('model.input', function (value) {
            if (value === 'password') {
              element.children(1).toggleClass('alert-box alert')
            } else {
              element.children(1).removeClass('alert-box alert')
            }
          })
        }
      }
    })
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this function:

```
link: function (scope, element)
```

`element` is your container div, and `element.children(1)` does not accept selector so it will get all the children. From [angular.element](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.element). Try:

```
element.children().eq(1)
```

Or

```
element.find("div")
```

Comment: thanks it's work. Is that mean the tutorial outdated? the angular.element already changed?

Comment: @Payne Chu: I did not look at the tutorial but it could be.